# pr2 gazebo headless not working

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am having a trouble with launching pr2 gazebo headless version.
I tried to launch launch/pr2.launch in pr2_gazebo package. It stops responding or  publishes broken tf messages. pr2_empty_world.launch works just fine but pr2.launch.

Does anybody know what is going on? It seems like the recent update broke the package.

[Screenshot from 2012-08-06 16:29:23.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13442957726919062.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40681/pr2-gazebo-headless-not-working/) by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 634 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jon Mace](https://answers.ros.org/users/1507/jon-mace/) on 2012-08-06**:
It doesn't seem that there are any messages published on /tf

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2012-08-06**:
view_frame showed me that a broken tf tree. some tf messages are missing and unconnected. BTW, I got the headless working. I had to launch the gazebo empty_world with setting argument "gui" false.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-06**:
how can I reproduce the error?

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2012-08-06**:
I just did roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch with newly installed desktop in precise-fuerte.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-06**:
Thanks, ticketed (https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/9/headless-mode-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I can confirm the ros released code 1.6.12 is indeed broken, but the gazebo trunk has been fixed. I am waiting to resolve some other issues with the trunk before making another patch release.  Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2012-08-07**:
Great. Thanks!